# Scrolling to the bottom of an element with Selenium [Python]

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scroll, selenium-chromedriver

I want to scroll down to the end of a dynamically generated element.
It's the instagram followers section. It looks like this:

[image]

I was able to locate the div/scrollable area.
But I have no idea how to scroll it.

Tried with a few scripts found online, but no success.

```
scroll=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/d   iv/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]")
scroll.click()
y=0
while y<10:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 100);") #line
    scroll.click()
    y=y+1
```

I used this piece of code. Scroll is the element. I click it and afterward scroll it down.
Just used an example to try to scroll the first 10 followers.It seems like the #line only scrolls one person at a time. And the loop does not have any effect. The whole while scrolls only one person down, like it would a simple #line command.
EDIT: The loop had no effect whatsoever. It was the click that (?) scrolled down one element.

```
main=driver.current_window_handle;
second=driver.window_handles;
time.sleep(1)

driver.switch_to.window(second[0])

for i in range(1,5):
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        time.sleep(1)
```

Please, if it involves a `js`, give me also the required library/declarations in order to execute `js` inside `python`. I don't know java, but I am able to interpolate how it works.

Thanks.

EDIT: I realized that the followers/following are some sort of inside window of the main page. So I did a window change and a scroll loop to see if it works.

My accounts got flagged by IG and I have a "try again later" situation. Not sure if it works. If you see any problem or so, or have any suggestions, I will watch the thread meantime.

Comment: That loop would scroll to the same exact coordinates every time, wouldn't it?  I don't think the coordinates are relative to the current scroll position.

Comment: To reduce the complexity try to send a key PAGE_DOWN to the scroller element